# Installing GDAL for python in Google Cloud Functions -- error when deploying

Tags: python, installation, pip, google-cloud-functions, gdal

I've been unsuccessful in using GDAL in a Google Cloud Function with Python 3.9. I've included gdal in the "requirements.txt" file:

```
numpy
pygrib
requests
google-cloud-storage
gdal
```

But get the following error when deploying the function:

```
Build failed: .../setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 541, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 578, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
          build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
        File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
          cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
        File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
          self.finalize_options()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-d9gag00y/gdal_e01a421a21914f03a3c89fd3914501b0/setup.py", line 255, in finalize_options
          gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
        File "/tmp/pip-install-d9gag00y/gdal_e01a421a21914f03a3c89fd3914501b0/setup.py", line 194, in get_gdal_config
          raise gdal_config_error(traceback_string + '\n' + msg)
      __main__.gdal_config_error: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-d9gag00y/gdal_e01a421a21914f03a3c89fd3914501b0/setup.py", line 87, in fetch_config
          p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
          raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-d9gag00y/gdal_e01a421a21914f03a3c89fd3914501b0/setup.py", line 188, in get_gdal_config
          return fetch_config(option, gdal_config=self.gdal_config)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-d9gag00y/gdal_e01a421a21914f03a3c89fd3914501b0/setup.py", line 90, in fetch_config
          raise gdal_config_error(e)
      gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'
      
      Could not find gdal-config. Make sure you have installed the GDAL native library and development headers.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.; Error ID: c84b3231
```

Reviewing other similar posts, e.g. [GDAL package missing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/python-gdal-package-missing-header-file-when-installing-via-pip), it seems that the GDAL library/headers needs to be installed, `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev`, before the `pip install gdal` will work. Given that I can't run apt-get for a cloud function, does anyone have a fix or workaround?

Comment: Just found this feature request for GDAL libraries: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178647869](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178647869). May mean it's not currently possible in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki to help other community members that will encounter this issue:

GDAL Libraries is not supported by Google Cloud Function at the moment. However, you can use Cloud Run for special cases where you have full control over the container.